# Outlook 2016 Keyboard Shortcut Alt+M for opening a calendar of another person is blocked by “TellMe” function

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I often need to look into the calendars of my colleagues. I already use the Shortcut Ctrl+2 to switch to calendar mode in Outlook. Now it would be very nice to open the Calendar via another shortcut. And there is the shortcut Alt+M. If you hit the Alt key in outlook 2016 (Office 365) you'll see it. But unfortunately, when I use Alt+M the cursors jumps into the "tellme" function. Instead, I want to use the shortcut to select the calendar of another person. Any way of how I can do that? TellMe cannot be hidden, can it?

Thanks, Hannes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Outlook doesn't provide an option to customize keyboard shortcuts.. You could see the thread below:
[enter link description here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/426cc46a-a93e-47c7-8700-8eaee607819e/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-outlook?forum=outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it. I was misled by the position of the displayed letters when hitting the "Alt" KEy.
The solution to my problem (in a German Outlook) is:
Alt+R,KA,A
Ok this is not very fast but at least feasable.
Is there a chance to record a Macro for that?